# sum the values of dictionary only if the keys is equal or greater than x

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Given a dictionary which contains keys and values, and I want sum the values based on the keys value. For example, `{1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40, 5:50, 6:60}`, and sum the values only if is **equal or greater than 2 in keys**, which output is **200**.

```
x =2
    count = 0
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        while key == x:
            count += 1[value]
```

And my output is none, and I don't know what I am missing on.

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `1[value]` to mean?

Comment: Where you have written `while key == x:`, what do you expect that to mean? Do you think that `key` can change *inside* that loop, or `x`? If so, how?  If not, how do you expect the loop to end?

Comment: The function of count += 1 is used to sum up the value but I don't know am I correct..

Comment: I don't think we can help you here, because very little of what you're writing in your code makes any sense at all. You need to follow and understand a tutorial, and Stack Overflow is not the right place to get help with that understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your way of iterating over the dictionary items is correct, but inside the loop, you need to check if the current key is greater than or equal to your required key. Only then you should increment the count with the value corresponding to that key which can be retrieved in this way - `dictionary[key]` or you can simply add the value like `count+=value`

```
dictionary = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40, 5:50, 6:60}
x=2
count = 0
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if key>=x:
        count += dictionary[key]
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your code is incomplete and won't run as-is, so it's difficult to speculate why you're getting an output of None.
2. in your requirements you mention "equal or greater than 2" but your code has "key == x". This should be "key >= x".
3. inside your for loop you have a while. Fixing other issues this would result in an infinite loop. You want an if, not a while.

fixing those things and making an assumption or two, your code would be:

```
x = 2
count = 0
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key >= x:
        count += value
```

Alternately, you could write it in a single line of code:

```
sum ( v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k >= x )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to do as below:

```
count = 0
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key >= n:
        count += value
```